# Duplicate symbol when linking C++ and Fortran

Tags: c++, fortran, gfortran

I am getting a duplicate symbol error when linking fortran and C++ code, and I'm at a loss as to why.

I have the following fortran code, `simple.f90`:

```
module foo
    use iso_c_binding
    integer(kind=c_int) :: bar
end module foo

subroutine print()
    use foo
    write(*,*) bar
end subroutine print
```

and I have the following C++ driver, main.cpp

```
extern "C"
{
  int __foo_MOD_bar;
  void print();
}


int main()
{
  __foo_MOD_bar = 42;
  print();
  return 0;
}
```

What I would like to do is assign the module foo/bar variable to a value and print it from within the Fortran subroutine.

However, when I compile and link

```
gfortran -std=f2003 -fno-underscoring -c simple.f90
g++ -c main.c
gfortran main.o gfortran.o -o out
```

I get a duplicate symbol error

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable out
duplicate symbol '___foo_MOD_bar' in:
    CMakeFiles/out.dir/main.cpp.o
    CMakeFiles/out.dir/simple.f90.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
```

```
 nm simple.f90.o
00000000000000f8 s EH_frame1
00000000000004cc S ___foo_MOD_bar
                 U __gfortran_st_write
                 U __gfortran_st_write_done
                 U __gfortran_transfer_integer_write
0000000000000000 T _print
0000000000000078 s lC0
```

```
nm main.cpp.o
0000000000000388 S ___foo_MOD_bar
0000000000000000 T _main
                 U _print
```

I'm at a bit of a loss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `int __foo_MOD_bar;` defines a variable and not merely declares it (as the `extern "C"` block changes linkage only), and Fortran code presumably does the same. Try adding explicit `extern` specifier to the variable itself, like:

```
extern int __foo_MOD_bar;
```

(`extern "C" int __foo_MOD_bar;` should work as well IIRC, inside or outside the `extern "C"` block).

Alternatively, you can do replace variable definition with declaration in the Fortran part, but I don’t know that language so can’t explain how.

Comment: adding the `extern  to each within the extern "C" resolves it. Why does it require an extern on each variable?

Comment: The `extern "C"` *block* doesn’t convert variable definition to declaration. That is, there were two variables defined, in the Fortran code, and in the C++ code, with the same name. That is not allowed.

On the other hand, `extern` specifier on the variable itself make it a *declaration*, not definition. That is, a reference, which is then resolved to the variable defined in the Fortran code (as it has the same name).

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage for more information (esp. notes, there is a similar example).

Answer (score 1):

When using `extern "C"` with a block, the variable definitions inside the block do not get the external storage-class treatment. There is a fairly good reason for that behaviour, namely cases like

```
extern "C" {
#include <some_c_lib.h>
}
```

to make C header files usable in C++. If `extern "C" { ... }` was to modify all variable defintions into external declarations, bad things may happen.